# How to store different sets of user information using ASP.NET MVC Simple Memberships

Tags: asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

How do I store different sets of user information using Simple Memberships? For eg. I have two roles (doctors and patients) respectively. The extended user information to be stored for both the roles is somewhat different. Simple Membership creates a UserProfile table by default which I'd like to split into two tables to accomodate the user information for both the roles respectively.

Please suggest if and how this can be achieved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have Roles defined in your 'Roles' Table. Then, for a particular User, UserId and RoleId both are associated with each other in another Table named '_UserInRoles'. Now, Create another table maybe Named as 'UserAdditionalInfo' and 
make table structure as below

```
Id(PK)
UserId(FK)
RoleId(FK)
Column1
Column2
```

Now, you can save user additional data according to its RoleId and UserId in another table and when you need to display User Profile on front end, then may be you can use JOIN in these tables and return information.

Comment: Thanks. Note that apart from the Membership table that is created automatically, I have two tables to store extended information based on the role. While one is UserProfile (which will be used to store doctors), the second is PatientsProfile (to store patient information). Now, when I call WebSecurity.CreateUserandAccount method at the time of adding a patient, I want to add a record to the PatientProfile. However, a record gets added to the UserProfile rather. I have tried to use WebSecurity.CreateAccount but it results in an error Provider encountered an unknown error. ideas?

Comment: if you want to do it this way, then you will not be using roles feature. So, what i'll suggest is that you have two different tables one is for doctor and another is for patients. Now, to add a patient in database table, you can use a LINQ query instead of using "WebSecurity.CreateUserandAccount()" and that query will create a patient row in your table. If the above answer helps then please accept that answer or let me know if this comment helps then i can edit my answer so it can help someone else.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean to say I should not be using SimpleMemberships in that case and handle the account management for different roles on my own in two different tables? If using SimpleMemberships and trying to create an account using WebSecurity.CreateUserandAccount, a row is being created in the memberships table and the UserProfile table which has the structure for storing doctors information only. So I am unable to use this approach when I am trying to add a patient.

Comment: What i mean to say is you should use SimpleMemberships only for doctor and to store patient data you should use another table and insert patient data using LINQ not by "WebSecurity.CreateUserandAccount". I hope this is a clear and straight answer. one request can you tell me what are the columns of doctor table and patient table. That will make it more clear.